# Intersection in MDX

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, olap

I recently ran into a problem in our SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services Cube. Imagine you have a simple sales data warehouse with orders and products. Each order can be associated with several products, and each product can be contained in several orders. So the data warehouse consists out of at least 3 tables: One for the Products, one for the Orders and one for the reference table, modelling the n:n relationship between both.
The question I want our cube to answer is: How many orders are there which contain both product x and product y?
In SQL, this is easy:

```
select orderid from dbo.OrderRefProduct
where ProductID = 1
intersect
select orderid from dbo.OrderRefProduct
where ProductID = 3
```

Since I am fairly proficient in SQL, but a newbie in MDX, I have been unable to implement that in MDX. I have tried using distinct count measures, the MDX-functions `intersect` and `nonempty` and subcubes. I also tried duplicating the dimensions logically (by adding the dimension to the cube twice) as well as physically (by duplicating the data source table and the dimension).

On http://www.zeitz.net/thts/intersection.zip, you can download a zip file of 25kB size which contains an SQL script with some test data and the Analysis Services Solution using the tables.

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 and its Analysis Services counterpart. Performance considerations are not that important, as the data volume is rather low (millions of rows) compared to the other measure groups included in that cube (billions of rows).

The ultimate goal would be to be able to use the desired functionality in standard OLAP (custom calculated measures are ok), since Excel is our primary frontend, and our customers would like to choose their Products from the dimension list and get the correct result in the cube measures. But even a working standalone MDX-Query would greatly help.

Thank you!

**Edit March 12th**
Did I miss something or can't this be solved somehow?

If it helps to build the mdx, here is another way to get the results in sql, using subquerys. It can be further nested.

```
select distinct b.orderid from
(
select distinct orderid from dbo.OrderRefProduct
where ProductID = 1
) a
join dbo.OrderRefProduct b on (a.orderid = b.orderid)
where ProductID = 3
```

I tried something like this with subcubes in mdx, but didn't manage to succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a go - you can download my solution from here:

http://sdrv.ms/YWtMod

I've added a copy of your Fact table as a "Cross Reference", Aliased the Product1 dimension as a "Cross Reference", set the Dimension references to Product independently from your existing relationships, and specified the Many-to-Many relationships.

It is returning the right answer in Excel (sample attached).

You could extend that pattern as many times as you need.

Good luck!
Mike

Comment: It works! Fantastic. Give me a day or two to fully understand what you actually did :-D

Comment: There is one tiny problem: I managed to extend the solution so it uses 3 product-dimensions (2 of them cross-referenced, like you did), this works perfectly. Now when a user (and we do have this kind of users) selects a product in the cross-referenced dimensions product2 and product3, but leaves the main product-dimnension product1 as it is, then the result is wrong. We could use the cube calculations to force output null in this case, but is there a way to make it calculate correctly? I can supply a solution + excel file for this case if necessary.

Comment: On the Dimension Usage tab, the Regular relationships should only exist for one cross-reference fact & dimension pair, i.e. you should not have multiple regular relationships in the same column or row for the cross-reference facts & dimensions.

Comment: Thats not quite what I meant. If a user ignores the first product dimension, but uses the other product dimensions, then the result is wrong. Everything else does work. See [this Screenshot](http://www.zeitz.net/thts/screen1.png) for the excel file, and [this Screenshot](http://www.zeitz.net/thts/screen2.png) for the dimension usage tab. You can download the excel-file and the solution here: http://www.zeitz.net/thts/intersection2.zip. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It looks like you have changed the measure - previously it was a Distinct Count of OrderID, now you have a count of the Order-Product combinations?  I would reinstate the Distinct Count of OrderID.

Comment: That did it, thanks! Will the distinct count measure be sufficient in only the main measure group, or will I also have to use it in the hidden measures?

Comment: Distinct Count is only needed in the main measure group.  The hidden measures are best left as Count - less work for the server.

Comment: I have already described it above and you can use Thomas' and my links to download working solutions (with SQL schema and data) showing before and after.  Review those and then feel free to ask any specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

an other way to deal with this in SQL (I know it works, but I didn't test this query) is to use double negation

```
select distinct orderid 
from X 
where TK NOT in (
   select TK 
   from X x_alias 
   where productid NOT in (id1,id2)
)
```

I'm pretty sure you can do the same in MDX.

Comment: The question is asking for MDX query, not SQL dear.