# SSAS calculated measure: Access relational database

Tags: many-to-many, ssas, olap, measure

I recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250014/intersection-in-mdx) about many-to-many relationships and how they can be used to calculate intersections that got answered pretty fine. Now, there is another nice-to-have requirement for our cube to extend that to more data. The general question remains: `How many orders contain both product x and y?`

However, the measure groups are now much larger, currently about 1.4 billion rows. I tried to implement that using the method described in the other post, with several hidden cross-referenced measure groups. However, this is simply too much for our hardware, the cube is reaching sizes next to 0.5 TB, and querys take several minutes to complete.

Now I would try to use another option: Can I access our relational database in a calculated measure? It seems I can, using UDFs like [described in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713711(v=vs.85).aspx). I could write a Function in c# that queries our relational database and returns all the orders that contain the products chosen by the user. But in order to do that, I need to supply all the dimensional data the user has selected to the UDF. I also need the UDF to return the calculated value so it can be output as the result of the calculated member. Is that possible? If yes, how? The example microsoft provides only includes a small deterministic string-function as the UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my own results:

It seems to be possible, though with limitations. The class `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdServer.Context` can provide you with the currentMember of each Hierarchy, however this does not work with Excel-Style-Subselects. It either contains a single member or the AllMember.

Another option is to get the MDX query using the dmv `SELECT * FROM $System.DISCOVER_SESSIONS`. There will be a column on that view which contains the last mdx query for a given session. However in order to not overwrite your own last query, you will need to not use the current connection, but to open a new one. The session id can be obtained through `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdServer.Context.CurrentConnection.SessionID`.

The second approach is ok for our use-case. It **does not** allow you to handle axes, since the udf-function has a cell-scope, but you don't know which cell you are in. If anyone of you knows anything about that last bit, please tell me. Thanks!